# Send HTTP request to ip address with node red

Tags: node-red

[image: test run]

how do I convert a switch node using greater or less than control to send a html string like this to a specific IP address:

```
/setS.html?Sensor=00&State=1&u=user&p=pass
```

ie it works if I type this directly to browser

```
192.168.0.2/setS.html?Sensor=00&State=1&u=user&p=pass
```

this is from raspberry pi 3b+ to pokeys57e device to switch the poextbus relays. I have the output and pokeys nodes from github but pin id only references digital out pins.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `http-request` node not the `tcp-out` node.

Assuming it is a fixed string you want to send then you would just place the following in the `http-request` node's URL field.

```
http://192.168.0.8/setS.html?Sensor=00&State=1&u=user&p=pass
```

If you wanted to make it some what dynamic based on the input then you can use mustache syntax to do variable replacement e.g.

```
http://192.168.0.8/setS.html?Sensor=00&State={{msg.payload.state}}&u=user&p=pass
```

This would take the value of `msg.payload.state` and insert it where `{{msg.payload.state}}` in the URL.

Also this is not a html string, it is a http query.

Comment: thank you for the help. after the 2nd switch node should a use a function node on each out put of the switch to change the msg.payload.state to 1 or 0. both switch nodes are sending msg.topic from pokeys do I change that and then add the function. Could I change the second switch node to msg.payload.state then a function or do I need to use a change node.